# Is Python specifically suited for AI problems than other popular languages?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

This question arose in my mind while I was trying to pass the open MIT 6.034 course dedicated to AI field. It seems to me, that Python is much more preferrable, than most of other popular languages. The different collections of courses for AI study available online strongly support this evidence.

I'm not talking here about special-purpose languages like CLIPS (which was specifically designed for production systems) or R (for statistics), I'm talking about languages like Java, C#, C++. What makes Python so specifically well suited for AI problems that scientists prefer this language for the field?

That means, is there a set of well-designed libraries and frameworks in Python for this task, that make it preferrable, or is it the language itself, it's syntax and semantics, that turns out to be so efficient for AI?

Comment: ultimately this is a very broad topic, but for me it comes down to the expressive nature of Python and powerful support from packages like NumPy and Pandas.  Python, in general, allows me to focus almost immediately on processing data and not on writing boilerplate to even get up and going.